# How to catch cancelled cell edit in DataGridView?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events

I can easily track cell change in DataGridView:

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) _
        Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    If TypeOf e.Control Is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl Then
        RemoveHandler e.Control.TextChanged, AddressOf ProcessCellChange
        AddHandler e.Control.TextChanged, AddressOf ProcessCellChange
    'ElseIf TypeOf e.Control Is ...etc.
    End If
End Sub
```

I can visualize this change when user is typing. But how can I catch "undoing" stuff when user pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> and cancelled editing?

**Example:** Cell contains `Hello`, I change it to `BYE` and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Now `Hello` text is back in the cell. What event will fire after the text was undone so I can update dependent control(s) with `Hello`?

When I'm checking for events `Leave` of `LostFocus`, they still give me text `BYE`, because they occur before text was reverted. Any idea how to get the `Hello` after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>?

Comment: Why don't you just wait for the user to accept the change to update whatever depends on the value?

Comment: @JoshPart – In column "A" I have text input, in column "B" I have filenames created based on that text input (but they are manually adjustable). I wanted to have "B" always up-to-date on changes of "A", even in "A" got cancelled, so if user presses "Generate" button, there are always correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved (or worked around?) the problem for now by disabling "undo on cancel". If user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd>, no remarkable undo is performed. It was accomplished by updating underlying DataGridView cell at every value change of `EditingControl`, so then, even if there is a reversal on undo, it has no effect:

```
Private Sub ProcessCellChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
'...
    content = DirectCast(DataGridView1.EditingControl, Control).Text
    currentRow.Cells(ContentColumn.Index).Value = content
'...
End Sub
```